# NRF51 - iOS BLE advertising interval - Increase speed of connection

Tags: ios, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, nrf51

I am looking at speeding up the connection time between my iOS application and the peripheral.
I have looked up Apples Documentation on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1931/_index.html

Originally (prior to reading the doc above) I had the advertising interval set to 2 seconds to, what I had thought would be, a good compromise between power consumption and connection time. Having read the documentation further I have changed the interval to *1285 ms*.
`#define ADVERTISING_INTERVAL 2056` `ble_obj.setAdvertisingInterval(ADVERTISING_INTERVAL);`
The device is always discovered quickly by the app but the problem comes when trying to connect.

However, I have seen no increase in speed in connection time between my application and the peripheral device. Connections between the devices can take anything from 3-4 seconds up to 30+ seconds.

Is there something I am missing? Either on the peripheral or the central side?

Peripheral BT chip is the Nordic Semiconductor NRF51822.
On examining the devices advertisement packet on the Nordic Semiconductor app I can see that the advertisement interval normally varies from 1275 ms to about 1295 ms (as expected? due to the random time added to the advertisement packet)

**NOTE**
Have also tried with an advertising interval of *152.5 ms* and am still not seeing any major improvement in connection speed. I am , obviously, seeing a marked improvement in speed of discovery

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is normal. Don't expect fast connection setup with an advertising interval of more than a second.

Core Bluetooth uses a high duty scan window/interval for the initiation the first seconds. If it doesn't connect then it continues to scan with much more power restrictive parameters.

Comment: I have returned to this problem there recently, and have changed the advertising interval to 152.5 ms as per the documentation specified above, but again, connection is still no faster.

I am seeing no discernable difference between the speed with two separate devices, one with an advertising interval of 2 secs and the other at 152.5 ms.

Could there be something else I am missing, from either the iOS or device end.